# ADFS authentication using node.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, adfs, hapi.js

I'm trying to use ADFS authentication  for my Hapi.js applicatio.
I found only one option to do it using passport-saml but the examples there are for expressjs.
Anyone have an example how to do it using Hapi?
Thanks

Comment: Should be easy enough to convert code into a hapi auth strategy which can be used as a plugin.